# How to make persistent changes (survive after reboot) in the Windows registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, group-policy, reboot

I have a Windows 7 VM and I'm trying to modify the keys in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\SystemInformation` since I want to change the data in both SystemProductName and BIOSVersion from "VirtualBox" to the values in my actual physical machine. However, the changes I make are not persistent through a reboot.

Looking around I've found that the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive is reassembled upon reboot and that a GPO overseeing those keys could also be reverting my changes upon reboot. I tried changing the permissions of the `SystemInformation` folder by unchecking *Include inheritable permissions from this object's parents* and adding my user as the only user to have (Full-control) permissions on the folder. However, after reboot, these changes reverts back to their original settings (same users with the same permissions from before).

Therefore what can I do to make my changes permanent? I have been looking online but have not found any posts that describe how to do this effectively. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: There should also be CurrentControlSet\Control ...  Se if what you want is in the other ControlSet.   Use extreme caution.

Comment: @John is right.  Just touch CurrentControlSet.  ControlSet001 and CurrentControlSet are possibly the same key and linked (like a softlink).  For fun, you can see which control set is linked by looking at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Select`.  I know this doesn't help you but fun to know about.

Comment: The information you are trying to modify is volatile and comes from your firmware on boot.  In this case, faked VMWare firmware.  Perhaps you can do something on the VMWare end to modify what it is providing.  You can change the appearance of the System Product Name by editing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation`'->`Model` but it might not give you the results you desire.  I doubt you can fake the bios version but perhaps someone else will chime in.

Comment: Thank you @John and SeñorCMasMas, how may I know in Select which control set is linked. What am I meant to see and what does it tell me? Also the keys I want to modify are also in the CurrentControlSet but again how do I overcome the reboot key reset issue?

Comment: `how do I overcome the reboot key reset issue?` .. you don't.  It doesn't work that way.  Those keys are probably not even written to disk.  `how may I know in Select which control set is linked`.. you look at the key I specified and look for the `Current` number.